# is it possible to run a Tensorflow quantized model on GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have quantized a Tensorflow model using Tensorflow Lite, then I run inference on it. It seems that it only uses CPU.
Is it possible to run inference with quantized model on GPU?

Comment: Hi @Boubaker, there are some limitations to what TensorFlow ML operations, can be accelerated by the TensorFlow Lite GPU delegate. Please refer to this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu) for more details. Thank You.